# Append content section to video lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

### Setup

I have several thumbnails with a description (a heading + paragraph) under each thumbnail. When a thumbnail is clicked, a video is played in a lightbox.

The description is wrapped in a div with the class `.video-info`.

So far I have this first part working fine.

### Objective

I need to display the description (heading + paragraph) under the video in the lightbox.

Basically, I need to append `.video-info` to the video while it's playing in lightbox mode.

### Problem

I am unable to figure out where in the script I need to put the function to append the container `.video-info` to the video when it's being displayed in the lightbox.

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="link-lightbox" data-videoid="CuH3tJPiP-U" data-videosite="youtube"><img src="http://placehold.it/200/339?text=YouTube" alt=""></a>
        <div class="video-info">
            <h6>Heading</h6>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae consequuntur, labore animi assumenda aliquam asperiores!</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="link-lightbox" data-videoid="108210854" data-videosite="vimeo"><img src="http://placehold.it/200/903?text=Vimeo" alt=""></a>
        <div class="video-info">
            <h6>Heading 2</h6>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, nulla.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### jQuery script

```
$(".link-lightbox").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (window.innerHeight > 540) var a = (window.innerHeight - 540) / 2;
    var b =
        '<iframe src="" width="640" height="480" id="video-embed" style="border:0;"></iframe>',
        c = '<a href="#" id="close-icon"></a>',
        d = '<div class="lightbox" style="margin-top:' + a + 'px">',
        e = '<div id="back-lightbox">',
        f = '<div id="background-close"></div>',
        g = '<div id="window">',
        h = '</div></div></div>';
    if ($("body").append(g + f + e + d + c + b + h), $("#window").hide(),
        "youtube" == $(this).data("videosite")) var i =
        "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + $(this).data("videoid") +
        "?autoplay=1";
    else if ("vimeo" == $(this).data("videosite")) var i =
        "http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + $(this).data("videoid") +
        "?autoplay=1";
    $("#window").fadeIn(), $("#video-embed").attr("src", i), $(
        "#close-icon").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#window").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(this).remove()
        })
    }), $("#background-close").on("click", function() {
        $("#window").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(this).remove()
        })
    })
}), $(document).on("keyup", function(a) {
    27 == a.keyCode && $("#window").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).remove()
    })
}), $(document).on("mouseover", function() {
    var a = (window.innerHeight - 540) / 2;
    $(".lightbox").attr("style", "margin-top:" + a + "px")
});
```

### What I've tried

I think this can be done using `.append()` or one of those jQuery methods to attach elements to other elements:

```
if ($("body").append(g + f + e + d + c + b + h).append(".video-info")
```

I've also tried adding a variable in the list, but it doesn't work:

```
    h = '</div></div></div>',
    z = '$(".video-info")'; //I tried adding it here and adding the variable name below
if ($("body").append(g + f + e + d + c + b + h + z), $("#window").hide(),
```

### Demo

You can see a **[demo in CodePen here](http://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/f2d875a9a8593e8fb9109dba2c2d885b/?editors=1010)**

### Question

Any idea how to incorporate the description container into the video lightbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of my friend [Jake Boyles](http://codepen.io/jakeboyles/) we were able to modify the script and append the `.video-info` container to the video when it's being displayed in Lightbox mode.

The new script is this one (notice the comments in the code):

```
$(".link-lightbox").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var info = $(this).parent().find('.video-info').html(); //CREATE VARIABLE HERE
    if (window.innerHeight > 540) var a = (window.innerHeight - 540) / 2;
    var b = '<iframe src="" width="640" height="480" id="video-embed" style="border:0;"></iframe>',
        c = '<a href="#" id="close-icon"></a>',
        d = '<div class="lightbox" style="margin-top:' + a + 'px">',
        e = '<div id="back-lightbox">',
        f = '<div id="background-close"></div>',
        g = '<div id="window">',
        h = '<div class="video-info">'+info+'</div></div></div></div>'; //ADD THE .video-info CONTAINER HERE
    if ($("body").append(g + f + e + d + c + b + h), $("#window").hide(),
        "youtube" == $(this).data("videosite")) var i =
        "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + $(this).data("videoid") +
        "?autoplay=1";
    else if ("vimeo" == $(this).data("videosite")) var i =
        "http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + $(this).data("videoid") +
        "?autoplay=1";
    $("#window").fadeIn(), $("#video-embed").attr("src", i), $(
        "#close-icon").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#window").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(this).remove()
        })
    }), $("#background-close").on("click", function() {
        $("#window").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(this).remove()
        })
    })
}), $(document).on("keyup", function(a) {
    27 == a.keyCode && $("#window").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).remove()
    })
}), $(document).on("mouseover", function() {
    var a = (window.innerHeight - 540) / 2;
    $(".lightbox").attr("style", "margin-top:" + a + "px")
});
```

[The demo in CodePen](http://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/f2d875a9a8593e8fb9109dba2c2d885b?editors=0010) is updated.